# Check my javascript codes

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone check my javascript codes, if they are correct ? I am not able to see email alert. I tried to click submit button but after name alert, email isn't working.

```
function doValidate()
{
    if (document.appointment.requiredname.value =="")
    {
        alert("Please put your name");
        document.appointment.requiredname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var readmail = document.appointment.requiredemail.value;
    var checkatsymbol = readmail.indexof("@");
    var checkdotsymbol = readmail.lastindexof(".");
    if (checkatsymbol < 1 || checkdotsymbol+2>=readmail.length )
    {
        alert("Please put the correct email address");
        document.appointment.requiredemail.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.appointment.requiredphone.value =="" )
    {
        alert("Please put your phone");
        document.appointment.requiredphone.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.appointment.requireddate.value =="" )
    {
        alert("Please put your appointment date as DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.appointment.requireddate.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.appointment.requiredtime.value =="")
    {
        alert("Please put your appointment time as HH:MM AM/PM");
        document.appointment.requiredtime.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return ( true );
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting errors in your Javascript console? There's no such function as `indexof` and `lastindexof`. They're `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `return false;` from your `if` conditions in order to execute the folowing codes in a function

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: read the question **but abfter name alert, email isn't working**

Comment: well i mean i am actually validating the form. when i try to fill the form and not entering any field, then try to click submit. I get first popup that says enter the name. After entering the name, i won't see any error because i didn't fill the remaining fields.

Comment: @SaranshKalia: have you tried after removing **return false** ?

Comment: @nauphal If he removes that, the form will submit even if there are errors.

Comment: can u check here,  i uploaded the page on my server

http://www.99degreesnorth.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

wirte 'indexOf' not 'indexof' replace:

```
var checkatsymbol = readmail.indexof("@");
var checkdotsymbol = readmail.lastindexof(".");
```

with :

```
var checkatsymbol = readmail.indexOf("@");
var checkdotsymbol = readmail.lastindexOf(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

```
var checkatsymbol = readmail.indexof("@");
var checkdotsymbol = readmail.lastindexof(".");
```

should be:

```
var checkatsymbol = readmail.indexOf("@");
var checkdotsymbol = readmail.lastIndexOf(".");
```

Comment: i did change it but same issue,

Comment: I'm getting an error because you misspelled `lastIndexOf` as `lastindexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=document.appointment.requiredemail.value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
```

This snippet to validate email should work!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably head for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), a StackExchange Forum